# Почему не работает псевдокласс :hover в Chrome?

Tags: вёрстка, html, css

Изменю немного вопрос,
Не работает в Chrome Версия 27.0.1453.110 m
Работает в FireFox 19.0.2
Работает в IE 10, 9, 8 (ниже уже не надо)
В других браузерах не проверял, может кто-то встречался с подобным?

html

```
<div class="menu_header_first">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active">Пункт 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Пункт 5</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

css

```
.menu_header_first {
    background-image: url("images/bg/menu_header_bg.png");
    height: 45px;
}

.menu_header_first ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    margin: 6px 25px 0;
}

.menu_header_first ul li a {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu_header_first ul li a.active {
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 1.000em;
}

.menu_header_first a:hover {
    display: block;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: «.menu_header_first ul li a» — каскад это плохо, познакомтесть с БЕМ. Максимальный каскад, который я себе позволяю — один уровень. Тобишь, можно написать «.menu_header_first ul {…}», «.menu_header_first li {…}», «.menu_header_first a {…}», но если каскад двух- и более уровневый, то нужно вводить дополнительные классы, а не строчить что-то вроде «.menu_header_first ul li ul a {…}» (задаем стиль для ссылок на втором уровне меню, например) и прочий ад.

Comment: БЕМ *(который вообще-то БЭМ)* - это не догма и не то, чем пользуются все. Не надо придираться к структуре вместо ответа на вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть я что-то не так понял ...?

Посмотрите [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/gMfNn/).

Comment: Странно( Теперь я вообще не понимаю, почему(

Comment: Спасибо, оказалось причина не в этом, не хватало свойства display:block. Теперь всё заработало как надо было)

Answer (score 0):

Не юзайте `inline-block` в менюшках. Лучше `float: left;`

Comment: Аргументы?

Comment: inline-block не кроссбраузерный. это css3. Для ИЕ8 и меньше нужно дописывать дополнительные стили, типа *display: block; и zoom: 1;

Зачем этот гемор, если с флоатом все прекрасно работает. display: inline-block нужно юзать в других ситуациях, например список товаров в категории отобразить. Вот там связка display: inline-block + vertical-align: top будет идеальной. Плюс для ишаков дописать *display: block; и zoom: 1;

Comment: Ну почему же — css3? [Если верить](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display), IE8 вполне хорошо понимает.

За остальное — спасибо.

Comment: сори, ошибся. но в данной ситуации его лучше не использовать

Comment: Единственный недостаток `inline-block` - это пробелы между элементами. `float: left;` же себя ведет просто ужасно если элементы разные по высоте!

Answer (score -1):

`hover` не будет работать, например, для `label` если метка относиться к радио-кнопке, которую нужно стилизовать и мы кнопку сделаем `display:none;` часто нужно, чтоб стилизовать радио-кнопку. Вот пример.

```
<input id="r_1" type="radio" value="2" name="gbvote" style="display:none;"><label for="r_1">текст для радиокнопки</label>
```

В итоге, в хроме не работает `hover`, а вот в файрфоксе все отлично
господам из хрома стоило бы поучиться у файрокса в нем всегда меньше багов
решение задать ширину и высоту радиокнопке = 0 вместо `display:none;`